# How to define a new css style for a tag that already has a style inside one of the html divs?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I already defined a specific style for `<h2>` inside the CSS stylesheet as following:

```
.body h2 {.............}
```

But now I want to define another style for `<h2>` which is in the sidebar of the website. I tried many times to define a new style for it as following:

```
div sidebar h2{.......}
```

But this style did not render. Each time the first style is the dominant style. I don't know why. The following is a part of my code to clarify the problem that I am facing

```
<div class="body">
<div class="body_resize">
<h2> ......... </h2>
<div class="news">
<div id="sidebar">
<h2> ................ </h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `div sidebar h2{ ... }` should be `div #sidebar h2` because "sidebar" is not a node name (`<sidebar></sidebar>`) but an ID.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
div#sidebar h2 { ... }
```

You should also read about selector specificity:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0):

You should give the style as

```
#sidebar h2{
}
```

The "#" represents the id for the div.